# Excel Format Cells based on adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba, format

Good day everyone,

I have a spreadsheet with whole numbers, decimals and percentages, all displaying as decimals, but the users want to see it as properly formatted .

How would I go about changing this using VBA?

To give you an idea of what I have been trying - putting this into Col 14 and 15 respectively, for the Macro to read, as explained in more detail just below:

> Sub Macro1()
>
> For Each cell In Range("A2")
>       ' print current number format
>       Debug.Print cell.NumberFormat
>       ' apply a different number format to adjacent cell
>
> ' cell one to the right of the active cell
>       cell.Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "@" ' @ means Text
>   Next
>
> End Sub

Now I have 117 000 rows and 12 columns for this macro to go through, to correct the formats. 
Col 2 through 13 is for the months in the year, with Col 13 containing text version of the Selection.Style and Col 14 containing the Selection.NumberFormat, which should be used to format the 12 cells to the left of it.

I can't seem to get hold of any sort of Loop to allow for cycling through all columns, and hope that you can assist with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ChangeFormat()
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B1:N" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        cell.NumberFormat = Range("N" & cell.Row).NumberFormat
    Next
End Sub
```

where `cell` in the loop will be each cell in the `Range("B1:M100")`.

Comment: Didn't you missed `.Cells`?

Comment: @LS_dev why would I need it? :)

Comment: What would the loop look like, to read the Style and Numberformat in Col 13 and 14 and apply it to the relevant cell?

Comment: @mehow - Thanks, I have updated the Macro, but it needs to look at my Col 13 and 14, where the Style and Numberformat is specified (might be different for every line item) and go back to A2 to apply the relevant format.

Comment: +1 I didn't assume `Range.Cells` as default property, so I usually use it explicit. Indeed, it works...

Comment: cell.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = cell.Offset(0, 13) - does work, now to get the Loop to go down all the way in Col B, then Start at the Top of C etc

Comment: @LS_Dev: I can used Range.Cells, as the range will be stable

Comment: @Herman your original problem, question should be solved now. Please do not edit your post with UPDATED PROBLEM or I HAVE A NEW PROBLEM NOW, as it invalidates the current answers. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @mehow, sorry for making the changes, but the original problem was to write a loop to loop through all columns and adjust the formats to that stipulated in Col 13. The problem remains to finish the loop.

Comment: I can't help you because I dont understand what you are trying to do - finish the loop is unclear.

Comment: Ok - I need to have the Range from B2:M100, with amounts in every cell. N2:N100 contains the Format eg. 0.0% or @.
I need to have a Loop that runs through each cell, and change the format to what is given in Col N.
Eg. B2,C2,D2 etc should have the format from N2, same for B3:M100.

Comment: Had some internet issues, it does loop through all the values, BUT it doesnt change it to the value as set in Col N, any ideas?